# Why doesn't my modified Bucket Policy allow my application to see the URLs for the AWS objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Issue**

We have an AWS S3 bucket created by an IAM user with an admin role.

Images are being stored in this bucket and I must retrieve the URLs for these images, so users can view them in an application. Currently we are able to store these images and view them in our application,
but the privileges for viewing the objects in the bucket have "Block Public Access" turned off and also a bucket policy where all principals can view the objects. This is shown further below.
The URL is formed by the base address of my bucket, with the key information appended.

I have attempted to introduce a new less permissive bucket policy, also shown below. But with this policy, my application will not show the images.
Images are also retrievable using the AWS CLI GetObject in both cases.

**Description**

The application uses the AWS SDK for C#. The credentials for the IAM account have been stored using AWS explorer.

The Access Key and Secret Access Key are stored in the credentials file by AWS Explorer and are used by the code.

**Example of code used to insert images in the bucket:**

```
    GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = subdirectoryPath + "/" + fileName,
        Verb = HttpVerb.PUT,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
    };
    string path = client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(path) as HttpWebRequest;
    httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
    httpRequest.Contentength = fileData.Length;
    Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

**Configuration Settings:**

This bucket has “Block all public access” in permissions turned off. (Need to tighten this up going forward)

I currently have Object Ownership as Bucket owner preferred. But have also tried to toggle this off.

Using the policy below all images show up in my application.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ...
```

When I modify the Principal as follows I cannot see the images in the application:

```
"Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountnumber:user/myuser"
            },
```

Any suggestions or other approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your actual desired state? Do you only want to grant access to a specific IAM User? Please tell us _what_ you want rather than _how_ you are attempting to do it.

Comment: I want to grant access to a specific IAM user. The user will "Put" the image into the bucket. 
Using the path variable below, I wanted to be able to access the object and show it in an application
const string baseURL = "http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
string path = baseURL + "/" + subdirectoryPath + "/" + fileName;

Comment: I am now quite confused about your situation. The policy you have shown above is for accessing content (`GetObject`), and it is attempting to restrict it so that only a specific IAM User can access (download) those objects. However, your comment above suggests that you want a URL that does not identify a user and is therefore public (so that anyone on the Internet can download the object). Your code sample is showing the creation of a pre-signed URL for _uploading_ objects. So, I'm now confused about what you're actually wanting to do and what problems you are currently facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are wanting to allow access to the bucket *only* from a specific IAM User.

If so, then you should **apply the policy directly to the IAM User** *without* using a Bucket Policy. It would be the same policy as you show, but the `Principal` is not required because the policy is directly applied to the IAM User.

If that IAM User is the only way you need to retrieve objects, then you can:

- Remove the **Bucket Policies**
- Activate **S3 Block Public Access**

Comment: ,Hi John,  I added the policy discussed to my IAM user. The Bucket policy was removed and Activate S3 Block Public Access was done. The "inline" policy is:{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
} However the images are not showing. When I click on them I get 403 forbidden. Did I not follow something? Thank you,Ken

Comment: The pre-signed URL will only work if the underlying credentials used to generate the URL have permission to access the object. So, check what credentials were used when running that code, and verify that those credentials (presumably coming from an IAM User or IAM Role) have permission to access that bucket. If that fails, please show the code being used to generate the pre-signed URL -- remember that this time it is a `GET` request, not a `PUT` request in the URL.

Comment: The code above generates the "Put" for the preassigned URL

Comment: Yes. If you are wanting users to `GetObject`, then the pre-signed URL will need to use `GET` (for download) instead of `PUT` (for upload). However, you don't need to use pre-signed URLs if the IAM User is accessing the objects via S3 API calls.  In fact, I'm somewhat confused about your system and what your users are doing.

Comment: Hi John, The goal is to have 1) The application writes an image object to the bucket using the "put" with my IAM user- this part is successful. 2) Trying to use the URL to the same object "put" in this bucket as a reference to access and display it in the same application. This the same application using this same IAM user. Using the URL to access the objects was working previously, with no blocking public access and the bucket policy used before. However as discussed that had policies which were too loose.

Comment: In that case, you simply need to generate another pre-signed URL (`Verb = HttpVerb.GET`) when providing a URL for accessing the private object. No bucket policy required.

Comment: Hi John, Is it correct to say that the images would need to be public if one used tried to use the URL to view them, without doing the GET? I'm not saying that this is an optimal solution at all.

Comment: If an object in Amazon S3 is public, then it can be retrieved by _anyone_ via a normal URL (eg `https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/file.txt`). If it is a private object, then you need to provide a pre-signed URL that appends information to the end to prove to S3 that the requester is entitled (for a short period of time) to access the object.

Comment: Thank you John! Your assistance is greatly appreciated.